# How do you have a background for a div to reach the bottom of the page when 100vh doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently in a web design class to learn to code, but I have been struggling with a code and *cannot* figure it out for the life of me.

I have my portfolio website I'm currently working on and cannot figure out how to get the background color of my main section to go all the way to the page. If you look in the attached screenshot, my main section won't go to the bottom of the page. I have tried `height: 100%` and `height: 100vh` with no luck.

Photo of problem:

[image]

Coding is to much to post because I'm not even sure what could be causing it...however, the website link is here if you could look at the page source:

http://cherylju.com/com6338/p1_Ju_Cheryl/about.html

Any help would be amazing! I've been trying to figure this out for hours now.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to get a hint of what is needed for questions on Stack Overflow. See also the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552).

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on how to write questions that best enable the community to provide assistance.  So you are aware, [it is generally not considered acceptable to post a link to your code on a third party site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it); doing so creates numerous problems.  Instead, you should aim to create a [mcve] in the body of your question.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Whenever you use percentage units you have to ask yourself "What is this a percentage of?" In this case when you set a height to 100% it is in relation to its parent element. In your case the parent element is the <main> tag. There is no height set on <main> so you cannot calculate a percentage of its height if it isn't set.  A quick fix for you would to just set the height of your section to something large such as 120vh. This create the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you sections side by side inside a `div` and give it the property `display:flex`

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <section class="secondary-page"></section>
    <aside class="resume"></aside>
</div>
```

Doing it you 'll notice inmediate changes (including what you are looking for) but the order of the sections will be changed... Then, You can get rid of `float` that it's not at all the best option for your goals... specially if badly used (you don't use float right to an element and float left to the other... both need same direction).

More about flex [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)